# Getting real path from image Uri is not working on api 19

Tags: android, background-image, android-linearlayout

I am trying to set a LinearLayout background image from Gallery.
To do this I am starting the Image gallery activity ,the URI returning from activity is fine but when I am converting that to a real path I am getting null value at Api 19...

```
   public static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    String retVal = null;
    if (contentUri != null) {

        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,
                proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        retVal = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for the KitKat version?

Comment: Yes I have found a solution for Kitkat

Comment: Would you mind sharing it? I am facing the same problem. You know you can post it and accept your own answer to get reputation points :)

Comment: @Snake Check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066398/getting-real-path-from-image-uri-is-not-working-on-api-19/20697777#20697777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS to the manifest

then

```
private void showImageGallery() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_INTENT_CALLED);
    } else {
        showKitKatGallery();
    }
}

private void showKitKatGallery(){
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
     intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
     intent.setType("image/*");
     startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_KITKAT_INTENT_CALLED);
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == GALLERY_KITKAT_INTENT_CALLED) {
    mChosenImageUri = data.getData();
    final int takeFlags = data.getFlags()
            & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    // Check for the freshest data.
    getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(mChosenImageUri,takeFlags);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but how do you get the path after all?

Comment: You can get the path from the Uri. like ImageView.setImageUri(mChosenImageUri)

Comment: Ohh I see so the takePersistableUriPermission method will change the URI so I can pass it to "getRealPathFromUri"

Comment: what should i add to "flags" in  takePersistableUriPermission and how to set to ImageView

Comment: Just look at onActivityResult() there is a variable called takeFlags.replace the flags with takeFlags and use imageView.setImageUri(mChosenImageUri)

Comment: @KousiK thanks , but from here , how can load the image in to a image view

Comment: @KousiK what does the GALLERY_KITKAT_INTENT_CALLED means ?? is it a constent ??

Comment: Just use imageView.setImageUri(mChosenImageUri) to load image to a imageView after takePersistableUriPermission().

Comment: GALLERY_KITKAT_INTENT_CALLED is not a constent,I have declared this as a final variable with the value 1 and passing the variable to startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_KITKAT_INTENT_CALLED); to check which Intent is calling in onActivityResult.

Comment: see the thing is that you have to check api first and call respective intent.if its below 19 then call the gallery intent,if not then call the gallery kitkat intent.and these are just a user defined values to check which intent has called in the onActivityResult().Hope to understand

Comment: @KousiK yeah i get ir but in here , it gives a compile error in GALLERY_INTENT_CALLED , it is in ur , is it variable ??

Comment: @Mr.G declare private final int GALLERY_INTENT_CALLED = 1; private final int GALLERY_KITKAT_INTENT_CALLED = 2;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44783/discussion-between-mr-g-and-kousik)

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

```
public static String getImgPathFromGallary(final Context context,Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = ((Activity) context).managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }
```